# How to calculate sample rate of any CSV data?

Tags: python, numpy, csv, sample-rate

Sample rate calculation is done of .wav data easily using following this code.

```
sampleRate, data = scipy.io.wavfile.read('ecg.wav')
times = np.arange(len(data))/sampleRate
```

If I want to calculate same sample rate of my .csv file what should I change in this code? I can read the data using `pd.read_csv('ecg.csv')` this command. But how can I calculate sample rate?

This is csv data:

[image]

Comment: csv and wav files are entirely different things. csv is like a spreadsheet table. what do you mean sample rate of csv?

Comment: I am yet to see an audio encoded in spreadsheet format. But even if that's the case, you should provide a sample data to show us how the csv is structured

Comment: sample rate means frequency of samples used in digital recording. how can I find this sample rate from csv data?

Comment: I know what sample rate means. The thing is csv isn't used for digital recording to begin with. You might convert wav -> csv for some computing/processing (but even then you should provide how the conversion is conducted or what the csv looks like). It's not like csv is a common sound format

Comment: @DevCl9 I have attached this csv file. from this data is it possible to calculate sample rate of data of column 'I'?

Comment: @Abc You count the number of rows, look at the last "Elapsed Time" entry, and then calculate the sample rate from that. It's a simple division, rows (=samples) per time. 10,000 rows in 10 seconds = 1000 Hz. It's not hard.

Comment: @Abc If you have the code that does it, post it as an answer below. This way the thread might help someone in the future.

Comment: @Tomalak I don't have any code. I just verified it with my csv data description. Thank you.

Comment: @Abc But *once you have written the code* that does this, please post it as an answer below.